# Kohana 3.3 Can't Join Tables

Tags: join, kohana

This is the structure of User table

```
id
role_id
username
```

and this is the structure of Profile table

```
id
user_id
full_name
```

I want to join the two and display the full_name of users who have role_id = n

```
$users = ORM::factory("User")->join("profiles", "INNER")->on("user.id", "=", "profiles.user_id")->find_all();
```

In the view I do this

```
foreach($users as $u) {
    echo $u->id;
    echo $u->full_name;
}
```

But kohana says

*full_name*

does not exists in the

*Model_User*

this means the join is not going on. Why ?

Another think, how can I label the query so that *echo $u->id* displays the User.id ? Because here User.id and Profile.id make things be ambigouos.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this? I think this is the answer

```
foreach($users as $u) {
    echo $u->id;
    echo $u->profiles->full_name;
}
```